# Replacing specific piece of code which has "/" in it via command line

Tags: command

There is 
../../../
in source code of my pages mistakenly. I need to replace code with
http://
My question is that how to write command to do this?
I am using WHM/cPanel with CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using this command.`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/..\/..\/..\//http:\/\//g' {} +`